# Query returns no results if my count row is 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database of users. I want to return info including the amount of groups they are in. I do the following SQL query

```
SELECT dbo.Users.UserId AS 'userId', 
       dbo.Users.UserName AS 'firstName', 
       dbo.Users.Surname AS 'surname', 
       dbo.Users.Photograph AS 'photograph', 
       dbo.Users.JobTitle AS 'jobTitle', 
       dbo.Users.EmailAddress AS 'emailAddress', 
       dbo.Users.Inactive AS 'inactive', 
       COUNT(dbo.UserGroups.userId) AS 'teams'
 FROM dbo.Users, 
       dbo.UserGroups
 WHERE dbo.Users.UserId = 27 
       AND dbo.UserGroups.UserId = dbo.Users.UserId
 GROUP BY dbo.Users.UserId, 
       dbo.Users.UserName, 
       dbo.Users.Surname, 
       dbo.Users.Photograph, 
       dbo.Users.JobTitle, 
       dbo.Users.EmailAddress, 
       dbo.Users.Inactive
```

This will return no results as user id 27 isnt in any groups when it should display the other info and the groups/ teams row should be 0.

This works fine with users that are in a group or multiple groups

Comment: . . Are you sure you are using MySQL?  `dbo` is usually associated with SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `left join` instead of implicit `inner join`:

```
SELECT dbo.Users.UserId AS 'userId', 
       dbo.Users.UserName AS 'firstName', 
       dbo.Users.Surname AS 'surname', 
       dbo.Users.Photograph AS 'photograph', 
       dbo.Users.JobTitle AS 'jobTitle', 
       dbo.Users.EmailAddress AS 'emailAddress', 
       dbo.Users.Inactive AS 'inactive', 
       COUNT(dbo.UserGroups.userId) AS 'teams'
 FROM dbo.Users
 LEFT JOIN dbo.UserGroups ON dbo.UserGroups.UserId = dbo.Users.UserId
 WHERE dbo.Users.UserId = 27 
 GROUP BY dbo.Users.UserId, 
       dbo.Users.UserName, 
       dbo.Users.Surname, 
       dbo.Users.Photograph, 
       dbo.Users.JobTitle, 
       dbo.Users.EmailAddress, 
       dbo.Users.Inactive
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because you are using an implicit INNER JOIN... use an explicit LEFT JOIN.

Try this:

```
SELECT dbo.Users.UserId AS 'userId', 
       dbo.Users.UserName AS 'firstName', 
       dbo.Users.Surname AS 'surname', 
       dbo.Users.Photograph AS 'photograph', 
       dbo.Users.JobTitle AS 'jobTitle', 
       dbo.Users.EmailAddress AS 'emailAddress', 
       dbo.Users.Inactive AS 'inactive', 
       COALESCE(COUNT(dbo.UserGroups.userId), 0) AS 'teams'
 FROM dbo.Users left join
       dbo.UserGroups on dbo.UserGroups.UserId = dbo.Users.UserId
 WHERE dbo.Users.UserId = 27  
 GROUP BY dbo.Users.UserId, 
       dbo.Users.UserName, 
       dbo.Users.Surname, 
       dbo.Users.Photograph, 
       dbo.Users.JobTitle, 
       dbo.Users.EmailAddress, 
       dbo.Users.Inactive
```

Comment: Doesnt seem to be working for me, I used a left join and it works now though :)

Answer (score 0):

I am going to suggest a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT u.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.UserGroups ug WHERE ug.UserId = u.UserId) as teams
FROM dbo.Users u 
WHERE u.UserId = 27 ;
```

Why do I prefer this approach?

- It makes the query simpler.  You don't have to list all the columns in the `GROUP BY`.
- Because there is no outer `GROUP BY`, this might be the most performance on most databases (assuming an index on `UserGroups(UserId)`).
- Note the use of table aliases to simplify the query.